# How do I use middleware, specifically Formidable, with Bogart to create a server response?

Tags: node.js, middleware

I'm building a node.js app using the [Bogart](https://github.com/nrstott/bogart) framework, and I would like to handle file uploads with [Formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable).

Here's my HTML (copied more or less straight from the Formidable docs):

```
<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="title"><br>
    <input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

And here's my server code:

```
var bogart = require('bogart'),
formidable = require('formidable');

var router = bogart.router();

router.post('/upload', function(req) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    var res = bogart.res();
    console.log("Beginning to parse files.");

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        console.log("Completed parsing files.");
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        if (err) {
            console.log("Upload error.")
            res.status(500);
            res.send('Error');
            return res.end();
        }
        res.status(200);
        res.send("Success.");
        res.end();
    });
    return res;
});

var app = bogart.app();
app.use(bogart.batteries);
app.use(router);
app.start(8991, '127.0.0.1');
```

When I submit the data, my node server logs `"Beginning to parse files."`, indicating it has received the POST, but `"Completed parsing files."`, in the form.parse() callback, never gets logged, so I figure something must be going wrong with the parse. I get no other errors--the client just waits for a server response indefinitely.

My hunch is that I don't understand how to use middleware properly, but I'm also not sure if it's correct to call Formidable middleware, though it does appear to be in the middle of things...

Comment: I think the first step is to ensure you're getting all of your form data into the request. The Bogart tests have a form upload test that essentially just takes the upload and pipes it back out, this might be a good way to check that your form data is well formed. https://github.com/nrstott/bogart/blob/master/examples/multipart-form/app.js

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks like it makes much more sense for me to use Parted than Formidable, though I'm still curious how one would go about using middleware that isn't built into Bogart. I guess the req that Formidable expects is pretty different from the req passed via the Bogart router.

Regarding Parted, do you know how to get access to things like on('part'), or to a file once it's put back together? The req body only contains the path to one part of the file.

Comment: I'm actually not sure on the exact details around how Parted pulls the file in, but I did find the js that does the magic: https://github.com/chjj/parted/blob/master/lib/multipart.js

Comment: It looks like the event handlers are hidden in the Parser object, which is not available in the Bogart implementation (yet). And I was wrong about the req containing only the path to a single part--it has the path to the whole file.

Comment: I have the same problem without using any framework.